# Implementing the Chow test in R: interpretation problems

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, chow-test

I was looking for something online, when I found this clear paragraph:

https://bookdown.org/ccolonescu/RPoE4/indvars.html#comparing-two-regressions-the-chow-test

It's short and very easy to read.

The example arrives to the conclusion that the 2 models, mod5 and mo6, are equivalent, since the p-value is very high the null hypothesis cannot be rejected.

Now I am pretty confused about the models we should use according to the possible results of this test.

```
Accept H0 --> use model 5
Reject H0 --> use model 6
```

Or something like that?

```
Accept H0 --> use model<-lm(wage~educ+black*female+south, data=cp4small)
Reject H0 --> use model 6
```

Answer (score 1):

The Chow test is a bit different from other regression hypothesis tests.

Much of the time, such testing involves nested models, where one model drops out of the other by setting some coefficients equal to zero. When you test those and “accept” the null hypothesis (more on that in a moment), you go with the simpler model, as there is no statistical evidence that the extra coefficients are nonzero.

With the Chow test, you are testing if the coefficients in two regression models are equal, since you got them with different data. An example could be testing if the coefficients for dogs are the same as the coefficients for cats. The interpretation of accepting the null hypothesis is that the coefficients are not different, so combine the two data sets and fit away, since the dog and cat groups are not different.

Consequently, accepting the null hypothesis means that you go fit a third regression where you combine your two data sets and treat them as equivalent, since you accept the notion that they lead to equal regression coefficients.

However, you need to be careful with the idea of accepting the null hypothesis, because failing to reject and accepting the null hypothesis are not the same. In particular, there Are multiple reasons why it might be difficult to detect a difference, with a small sample size and multicollinearity being possible culprits. If you have minimal power to detect a difference, then failing to find a difference is not impressive.

A way to think about it is this: if you report to someone that you found nothing, they would be quite reasonable to ask how hard you looked for a difference. Power quantifies how hard you looked for a difference between the regression coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

When you accept H0, you say that two models do not differ significantly. In this case, usually, simpler model is to be used (`mod5` in your case).